# Geocaching app for iOS?

Tags: ios, gps

I'd like to start geocaching - that game where you look for hidden things with a GPS and some hints. I'd prefer to have an app on my iPhone to do it - the prospect of actually putting coordinates into a GPS when my iPhone has a perfectly good GPS send chills down my spine.

The app must:

- Tap into the internal GPS
- Have a list of active caches
- Allow using the internal GPS to find them

It would be really nice if it could use the compass too, but that might be cheating. Is there an app that does this?

Comment: For android, there's [c:geo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cgeo.geocaching), which is a good (in my experience), and fulfills your requirements (except it's wrong platform, hence comment instead of answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the [Open Caching](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opencaching/id429776248?mt=8) app on Android a little, and it seems to work well.  Open Caching is different from the "Geocaching" app from Groundspeak (the main geocaching app that everyone uses) in that it is free and open, not only to search for caches, but to place them, etc and requires no membership and has no fees.  Here is a quote from OpenCaching.com:

> ### About us
>
> We believe that geocaching should be as free and open as the great
> outdoors, so we built a place where anyone with a compatible
> GPS-enabled device can upload, download and log caches. No
> subscriptions, membership fees or paid content.
>
> That doesn’t mean
> we’ve sacrificed any features, though. With support for a broad range
> of GPS-enabled devices, including those with eco-friendly “paperless
> geocaching” capabilities – it’s the perfect tool for everyone from
> beginners to advanced trekkers.

Of course, a downside to freedom is the fact that fewer people use Open Caching which means that there are less caches. I personally consider it worth the price however.

[image] [image]

Comment: The problem is, that OpenCaching app is from Garmin and their alternative portal, which has nothing to do with real OpenCaching, but it's something separate, and the number of caches is much much less that in both OpenCaching and GeoCaching.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ If you read my answer you will see I mentioned that. I personally think that its worth it though, not everyone has the money for groundspeak.

Comment: but I've written, this application is not for that OpenCaching that's the real alternative for GeoCaching.com, but a new portal with the same name, grounded by Garmin. So in fact, it ignores 2 biggest players...

Answer (score 0):

I think the Geocaching app from Groundspeak is really good. It also supports the Apple Watch, which is think is nice for geocaching:

https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/geocaching/id329541503